# Prove that $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+\ln^2 x}\,dx = \int_1^\infty \frac{\sin(x-1)}{x}\,dx $

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals, logarithms

I've found the following identity.

> $$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+\ln^2 x}\,dx = \int_1^\infty \frac{\sin(x-1)}{x}\,dx $$

I could verify it by using CAS, and calculate the integrals in term of [exponential](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExponentialIntegral.html) and [trigonometric integrals](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SineIntegral.html), then using identities between them. However, I think there is a more elegent way to prove it.

> How could we prove this identity?

Also would be nice to see some references.

Comment: Why not write as $$\int_1^\infty \frac{\sin(x-1)}x dx$$

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Hint.** One may observe that

> $$
> \frac1{1+\ln^2 x}=-\Im \frac1{i-\ln x}=-\Im \int_0^{\infty}e^{-(i-\ln x)t}dt,\quad x \in (0,1),
> $$

gives

> $$
> \begin{align}
> \int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+\ln^2 x}\,dx&=-\Im \int_0^1\!\!\int_0^{\infty}e^{-(i-\ln x)t}dt\:dx\\\\
> &=-\Im \int_0^{\infty}\!\!\left(\int_0^1x^t dx\right)e^{-it}dt\\\\
> &=-\Im \int_0^{\infty}\!\!\frac1{t+1} e^{-it}dt\\\\
> &=\int_0^{\infty}\!\! \frac{\sin t}{t+1}  dt\\\\
> &= \int_1^\infty \frac{\sin(x-1)}{x}\,dx
> \end{align}
> $$

as announced.

Comment: Just Brilliant +1

Comment: @Olivier Oloa seems that i took just the opposite direction, very nice (+1)

Comment: What is *that*? The script copies as -I?

Comment: @MarkC I'm not sure to understand the question, but $\Im $ stands for the imaginary part of any complex number, and $-\Im$ is the opposite number of $\Im$.

Answer (score 17):

Define $I(a)=\int_0^{\infty} e^{-(x+1)a}\frac{\sin(x)}{x+1}dx$.
Then $\displaystyle I'(a)=-\int_0^{\infty} e^{-(x+1)a}\sin(x)dx=-\frac{e^{-a}}{a^2+1}$, and since $\lim_{a\to \infty}  I(a)=0$, we have  $\ \displaystyle I(0)=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin(x)}{x+1}=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-a}}{a^2+1}da=\int_0^1\frac{dx}{1+\ln^2 x}.$

Comment: @A.G. fixed. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

A variant:

$$
\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x-1)}{x}dx=\Im\int_1^{\infty}\frac{e^{i(x-1)}}{x}dx= \quad (1)\\ \Im\int_1^{\infty}\int_0^{\infty}e^{i(x-1)-xt}dtdx=\Im\int_0^{\infty}\int_1^{\infty}e^{i(x-1)-xt}dxdt=\quad (2) \\
\Im\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-t}}{t-i}dt=-\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-t}}{1+t^2}dt=\quad (3) \\
\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+\log^2(x)}dx\quad (4)
$$

Explanation

(1)   $\quad\Im (e^{i x})=\sin(x)$

(2) $\quad$ $\frac{1}{x}=\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-xt}dt$ for $x>0$

(3) $\quad$ straightforward integration and $\Im\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)=\frac{\Im(\bar{z})}{|z|^2}$

(4) $\quad    e^{-t}=x,dt=\frac{-1}{x}$